# Wordpress Logout Link

Tags: html, wordpress

How could I add a logout link in the else portion of code, after the "echo $upme->display();" ...

```
<?php
global $upme;
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo $upme->show_registration();
echo $upme->login();
}
else    {   echo $upme->display();
    }
?>
```

I tried a few things including the below code but I keep getting internal error ...

```
<?php
global $upme;
$html1 = '<a href="'wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
echo $upme->show_registration();
echo $upme->login();
}
else    {   echo $upme->display();
            echo $html1;
        }
?>
```

Thank You

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: internal error 500, blank page, but when I restore old code everything works fine ...

Answer (score 1):

There's a small syntax error:

`$html1 = '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

500 is generally an "I can't find that" error. What page is this from? get_permalink may be returning false. Try outputting that function to see what you get back.

```
   <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```